# GCP load balancer can't connect to instance group: unhealthy upstream error

Tags: virtual-machines, load-balancing, https, http, gcp

#### **My Goal**

I want to connect my domain (`dashboards.example.com`) to my Google VM instance on port 3000 to showcase Metabase. I do so through a Google DNS and load balancer.

#### **My problem**

While trying to do so and accessing Metabase by going to `https://dashboards.example.com` I encounter a black screen showing me `no unhealthy upstream`. Furthermore, the health checks of the load balancers (`http` & `https`) say the backend services are unhealthy.

Is there anyone who might know what I am missing? I think I am overlooking something, however, while scanning the whole internet I can't seem to find the solution.

I tried things like re-starting my machine or clearing the domain and browser cache.

#### **The GCP setup**

**DNS**
My `A` class DNS points towards the two IP addresses from the load balancers (global external). When I ping the domain `dashboards.example.com` I correctly see the IP from one of the load balancers.

**Load Balancers**

- **HTTPS** I have a global external HTTPS load balancer with a Google managed SSL certificate. The frontend has an Ephemeral IP address and uses port `443`. The network service tier is `premium`. The backend `backend-https` points to an instance group, uses the `HTTPS` protocol with named port `https`. The instance group is in `europe-west4` and I added port number `3000`. The health check also points to this port. The routing route is the basic one with the `host` and `path` empty while pointing at the same backend.
- **HTTP** I also have a global external HTTP load balancer. The frontend has an Ephemeral IP address and uses port `80`. The network service tier is `premium`. The backend `backend-http` (different backend pointing to the same instance group) uses the `HTTP` protocol with named port `http`. The instance group is in `europe-west4` and I added port number `3000`. The health check also points to this port. The routing route is the basic one with the `host` and `path` empty while pointing at the same backend.

Then in the overview, the health checks already fail, I can't figure out why.

**Instance Group**
The instance group is in zone `europe-west4-a` and contains one VM instance. Furthermore it has two named ports called `https` & `http` both leading to port `3000`.

**Networking**
Everything is added in the same subnet or VPC. I added firewall rules to allow traffic from the health checks, SSH & the load balancers towards all instances in the network on TCP port `3000`.

**Extra**
Another weird thing I notice is that the health checks appear to be healthy the moment I shut the VM down.

---

Is anyone able to spot my mistake?

I tried things like re-starting my machine or clearing the domain and browser cache. I also tried to reconfigure the load balancers multiple times. Without success unfortunately.